# javascript question - why does "window.location" not ensure my spinner.gif animation works?

Tags: javascript

It seems when I use "window.location" as a means to redirect to the API when my longer running transaction is does not ensure the animation for the spinner gif I have works.  Any ideas how to fix this?  ie. I see the gif ok but it not being animated.  Is there another way in Javascript to force the redirect once the gif animation starts?

```
<div id="loading">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
   function show_spinner() {
     $("form").hide()
     $("loading").show()
     window.location = "/weekends/display"
    }
   window.onload=show_spinner;
</script>
```

CSS:

```
#loading {
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background:url(/images/ajax-loader.gif) no-repeat center #fff;
  text-align:center;
  padding:10px;
  font:normal 16px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  # border:1px solid #666;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  z-index:2;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: I was unable to find a "window.replace" in your post.  Could you explain a little more?  Sorry if I completely ignored your point or something >_<

Comment: Oops. Title should have been "window.loaction" like the code

Comment: perhaps what I am asking is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Unless someone can show me otherwise I'm proposing it is not possible....

I have solved my problem a different way however per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331603/jquery-why-does-this-code-work-in-step-through-but-not-in-real-time-show-spin)